# XMLHTTRequest mishandling the response status

Tags: javascript, http

```
let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
let FHIRserverAddress = '192.168.200.139:3012';
let url = 'http://' + FHIRserverAddress + '/model?starttime=' + startTime + '&endtime=' + endTime;
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        let currentModel = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        console.log('returning a valid model');
        return callback(null, currentModel);
    } else if (httpRequest.status != 200) {
        console.log('get model call failed');
    }
};
```

I can see the network call in Chrome dev tools and response status coming back is 200. The above call always get a 0 for the request status.

Anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: You're using `let` but not [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)?

Comment: This is very likely a cross-origin issue. Do you control the server at `192.168.200.139:3012`? If so, [enable CORS](http://enable-cors.org/). If not, it is by design that your script cannot read the contents of the cross-origin resource.